Get the maximum element of a two-dimensional array
Task
I want to get the maximum element of a integer two-dimensional array from input.
My code
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    /*********Begin*********/
    printf("Input m, n:");
    int m,n;
    int max=0; 
    scanf("%d,%d",&m,&n);
    int s[10][10];
    printf("Input %d*%d array:\n",m,n);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=m;j++){
            scanf("%d",&s[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int row,col;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=m;j++){
            if(s[i][j]>max){
                max=s[i][j];
                row=i;
                col=j;
            }

        }
    }
    printf("max=%d, row=%d, col=%d",max,row,col);




    return 0;
}

Tested case
// input
2,1

1

2

// output
Input m, n:Input 2*1 array:
max=2, row=1, col=2

what`s expected:
Input m, n:Input 2*1 array:
max=2, row=2, col=1

Why are the output row and col opposite? Or the output rows and columns are actually incorrect.

In one place you have for(int i=0;i<n;i++). In another you have for(int i=1;i<=n;i++). Think about what the difference is and what is wrong. Also look at int s[m][n];, for(int i=0;i<n;i++), and scanf("%d",&s[i][j]); and think about what is inconsistent between those.

i should go up to m, not n. And vice versa for j. This doesn't cause a problem when m==n, but will be a problem when they're not equal.

Your method would fail if all numbers in the matrix were negative.  Better to initialize max to INT_MIN from <limits.h>

Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? You may also want to read this: How to debug small programs?

If you're using m and n as dimensions of a two dimensional VLA that's allocated on the stack, I strongly suggest ensuring scanf succeeded and if so, sanity checking those values. It doesn't take much before multiplying two numbers will result in a much bigger array than should be allocated on the stack.

All the comments above are valid, and reflected in the code below. I'm giving you the solution not to give you the answer, but to show you some preferred coding practices, as you say you're a student, and coding style is something you would be advised to learn early on. Note in particular my copious use of white space, which makes the code much easier to read.
(I also pre-defined your matrix so I wouldn't have to enter all the numbers manually; you can undo this.)
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
#define NBR_ROWS 5
#define NBR_COLUMNS 5

    const int matrix[NBR_ROWS][NBR_COLUMNS] = {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        { 4, 5, 6, 100, 2 },
        { 3, 2, 1, 5, 6 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 5, 4 },
        { 3, 5, 6, 4, 8 }
    };
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int row;
    int col;

    for (int i = 0; i < NBR_ROWS; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < NBR_COLUMNS; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] > max) {
                max = matrix[i][j];
                row = i;
                col = j;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("max=%d, row=%d, col=%d", max, row, col);

    return 0;
}

